# MySQL Generating Singleton Bucket Histogram on varchar(64) Column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to generate the histogram on the `name` column in MySQL. I have the following table loaded from the smallbank benchmark:

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` ( `custid` bigint NOT NULL, `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`custid`), KEY `idx_accounts_name` (`name`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The table data looks like:

```
custid  name
0   0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1   0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
2   0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
...
```

`name` is just a `varchar(64)` representing `custid` making it unique; so, the number of rows is the same as the number of distinct values in the `name` column.

After running `ANALYZE TABLE smallbank.accounts UPDATE HISTOGRAM ON name`, however, I only get 1 singleton bucket:

```
{
  "buckets": [["base64:type254:MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAw", 1.0]],
  "data-type": "string",
  "null-values": 0.0,
  "collation-id": 255,
  "last-updated": "2022-12-06 14:41:26.493251",
  "sampling-rate": 0.018916425100134856,
  "histogram-type": "singleton",
  "number-of-buckets-specified": 100
}
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why do I get only 1 bucket even though `"number-of-buckets-specified": 100` and there are 4000000 distinct values in the `name` column? I would expect to have 100 buckets.
2. I cannot find any documentation on `type254`. How can I decode the value mentioned in the bucket?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a MySQL worklog that I found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=8707), for string datatypes (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, ...) only the first **42** characters are considered in the histogram.

In the above example, since all the values have `0`s as the first 42 characters, they are all considered to be equal and hence the one singleton bucket.

I still have not managed to find documentation on `type254` though!